# Is it possible to emulate a particular Android device brand?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to reproduce a bug that is specific to certain device brand, but Android Studio's AVD manager only shows generic system images.
[image: AVD Manager listing generic system images]

Is it possible to emulate a specific vendor's flavor of Android?

**Note:** I am not talking about device skins. They are irrelevant to the problem to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option on AVD to emulate some device brands, but https://www.genymotion.com/ can emulate some devices, but a list of devices is limited.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the documentation about emulating different brand flavors of Android in Android Studio, but you can look into some third party options.